# SWIG: String not being fully copied or displayed?

Tags: python, c, string, swig, memcpy

I need to send a pointer to a character array to one of my functions. To produce this char*, I use this function in one of my c files such that is called like this

```
charPtr = myProj.strAll ( 8 );
```

where strAll is:

```
char * strAll ( int size ) {
    return malloc( sizeof( char ) * size );
}
```

I then pass charPtr into a function like this:

```
myProj.Populate ( char* dataIn, char* dataOut, maxLen );
```

Populate copies dataIn into dataOut, using maxLen as the size restriction. It uses memcpy to copy it over through something like this:

```
memcpy ( dataOut, dataIn, maxLen);
```

Usage:

```
myProj.Populate ( "ABCD1234", charPtr, 8 ); //maxLen is the # of bytes I've allocated for charPtr.
```

However, when I tell python to print charPtr out, it will only print ABC.

Expected:

```
>>charPtr
'ABCD1234'
>>print charPTr
ABCD1234
```

Actual:

```
>>charPtr
'ABC'
>>print charPTr
ABC
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ABCD1234` has **8** characters. But you should also provide an extra byte for the termination character `\0`. Every C string should be terminated by `\0`.

```
myProj.Populate ( "ABCD1234", charPtr, 8 );
```

`charPtr` should be pointing to a location which can accommodate **9** characters out of which the last is to place the termination character.

And I amn't sure why are you just allocating **5** locations where you are trying to copy a string of **8** characters long.

```
charPtr = myProj.strAll ( 5 );
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying. I lost my train of thought. I meant to allocate for 8. And while I know there are 9 characters including that null character, I only used this as a sample function. It's actually a function which accomodates for that null character. However, the issue is that it only prints the first 3 characters. Even if I allocate something like 20 to the first str.